# Getting table row text from url

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to extract text from table cells. But I get `null` error. I would like to get the text inside `<p>` of each `<td>`. How would I do that?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").get(); //this is where Null error is thrown - but the URL is valid
     Element table = doc.select("table").first();
            Iterator<Element> iterator = table.select("td").iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                Log.e("CellText", iterator.next().text());
            }
```

HTML:

```
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="400">
          <tr>
            <td width="100">
              <p><strong>Text1</strong></p>
            </td>
            <td width="200">
              <p>Text2</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
         <tr>...
```

Comment: where you get the NullPointer?

Comment: I've tried the same code in standard java project and it worked. Is it possible that it doesn't work because I'm calling this code (separate class) from onUpdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your code in a simple java project too --> works

1. Does your url start with `http://`?
2. Do you run your code in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?
3. Does your android block internet access?
4. Please post a *stacktrace* or some *more information* about the exception

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark this answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in an AsyncTask and now it works.