# Jsoup issue on specific website

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```
public class Main extends Activity {

TextView liste1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new Ara1().execute();

}

public class Ara1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i;
        String result = "";

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bilyoner.com/iddaa/hazir-kupon-detay?yazar=populer").get();
            Elements element = document.select("li.iddaaTabsTab");

            if (element.size() > 0) {
                int x = element.size();

                for (i = 0; i < x ; i++) {
                    result = result + element.get(i).text();
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        liste1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        liste1.setText(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Aranıyor...");

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

When i connect this website "http://www.bilyoner.com/iddaa/hazir-kupon-detay?yazar=populer" and trying to parse, there is a problem that i couldnt get any data. I tried Jsoup on wikipedia and works great.

Also when i try this site on [try jsoup](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/jsoup.png/) it seems works without any problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try specifying a custom `userAgent` in the connection string?

Comment: Yes, I checked with Mozilla userAgent but couldnt get positive result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working perfect so it seems it's a problem of your android settings.

> there is a problem

Can you give as some more details (eg. stacktrace, error message, ...) about that? Without it's realy hard to say whats your problem.

Please also read my answers here: [Getting table row text from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157031/getting-table-row-text-from-url/15163292#15163292)

Comment: I edited my post with full code. Also internet_permission is active already but i cant get any data. Btw when i try another site for parse, it works perfect.

Comment: So there's nothing in your document but your code is executed?

Comment: Yes, code is executed, but nothing on textview. Is there any chance to protect the website for html parse?

Comment: I guess not. Normally you get an error page (but its content would appear in the document) if you are blocked. What you can do is writing `document` directly to an output (logger, textview, stdout, whatever) and check it there. Do this exactly after your `Jsoup.connect()` line so you can be sure there are no changes.